# Recording audio on Ubuntu

Tags: sound

I want to record audio on several channels (mic, guitar, bass), but I can't get a hang of it. I have a Fender Mustang II guitar amp which I'm connecting via USB and a mic that connects through the standard mic jack. So far I've tried installing FL Studio on WINE but I don't have the FenderASIO driver so the amp is not recognized by the program. I also tried both LMMS which didn't recognize any input device and Audacity which recognized all the inputs but I was able to record sound only from my amp and only on one track. Whenever I tried to record on multiple tracks the whole computer freezes and I have to do a hard reset. Any suggestins?

Comment: You might try Rosegarden, it is in the repositories, just use ubuntu-software-center. It is sort of a Cubase for Ubuntu.

Comment: will it work with my amp? Because it says in the description it's a MIDI sequencer, and my amp has nothing to do with MIDI.

Comment: This is a pretty good Instructable on creating a home recording studio in Linux.  Worth the read:  http://www.instructables.com/id/Linux-Recording-Studio-Software-Components/

Comment: Rosegarden is a midi and audio sequecer. I've downloaded it very recently and have not used it yet but I think it will work with your amp.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to get started with audio in linux i suggest you install Jack, it's a little intimidating at first but there are plenty of tutorials out there to learn from. Jack is an audio server that allows you complete control of where sound input and output goes.

One of the best DAWs for linux is called Ardour. it's a pretty hefty program but it's more powerful than audacity. I've worked as a sound engineer and have recorded 4-hour shows on 8 tracks with ardour.

For example let's say you want to take your guitar signal and send it through some guitar effects using Rakarrak, then send it to record to ardour, jack will let you do this.

I know this is straying from the scope of the original post, but my last suggestion is to invest in a cheap audio interface. There are plenty of linux-compatible ones out there and it will make your life easier, not having to deal with drivers for amps. just take the line out from the amp (or mic the amp), then put it into the interface and voila. even a small 2 channel one would work great, especially if you're just laying down ideas.

Answer (score 0):

There are going to be lots of possible answers to this question, and if you want to coninue this with Ubuntu, you have a lot of resources available.

tl:dr;

*I record* multichannel sound on Ubuntu using a [Behringer XR-18](https://www.behringer.com/product.html?modelCode=P0BI8) which I love to use - I can get 18 channels into the computer using Ardour, or a command line program using 'arecord' and 'sox' creatively.

I also run 4 channel sound using a usb interface also from [behringer](https://www.behringer.com/product.html?modelCode=P0BK1).  At church, we run [presonus](https://www.presonus.com/products/AudioBox-Mac-PC-iPad-Interfaces) devices, one 32 and one 4 channel.  I have never needed a driver, and run this in native Ubuntu.

---

You will be much better off using a multichannel interface (4 channels?) as coordinating sampling on multiple USB convertors is a real work of art.  This is probably why you are only doing single channel work.  You can theoretically set a single A/D convertor as the master clock for conversion, and cause the other sampling devices to slave to this, but it is not an insignificant problem.

---

Check out [ubuntustudio](https://ubuntustudio.org/) - although I just run Ubuntu, and load the programs I want.

---

Search around for various Linux Audio forums - there are a lot of creative people out there, using Linux for recording purposes.

---

Answer (score -1):

Ubuntu it self have a sound recorder and you can record the sound in many audio formats.you can get it by typing as sound in unity-dash.

you can try one more new  application with great features ,audio recorder.

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:osmoma/audio-recorder
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install audio-recorder
```

Comment: As far as I know, the sound recorder program can only record ONE channel, and I need more than one for the vocals and bass .. also an integrated effects mixer would be an advantage, something similar to what FL Studio and LMMS have